# Android Studio Emulator is already running. But I can't see the emulator on the windows and run my project

Tags: android

Installed android studio latest update and
started a project. But when I press run, emulator is not showing up.
And it say delete *.lock files. But I have already tried. Still couldn't see
the emulator. Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbUxc.png)

Answer (score 2):

On the AVD (Android Virtual Device), edit the device graphic setting from **Automatic** or **Hardware** to **Software**

Answer (score 1):

Go to the down arrow and click on the "Show on Disk" link like the attached image. You will get the list of all files, remove the file "hardware-qemu.ini.lock" and start again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers. After trying many ways of your suggestion, I finally decided to uninstall this version and reinstalled the previous archive and it now working fine. I still don't know the reason why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete All the *.lock files under .android/AVD/emulator_name/*.lock,
And right click the emulator wipe data,restart/rerun the emulator.

```
  It's restart the Avd and rebuild the gradle projects.
```

Comment: No .lock folder. Emulator still doesn't show up after Wipe data.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the task manager and see if there are "qemu-system-x86-64.exe", "adb.exe" and "emulator64-crash-service.exe" processes among the processes, and then you can kill these processes. so you can restart your emulator.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to completely delete the emulator when this happens. The files to delete should have a ".lock" extension:

[image]

You don't need to touch the configuration files.

You can easily find the files location by clicking on the arrow under the Actions tab (in the ADB manager), and selecting "Show on Disk".

Comment: Yes, I have already tried and deleted these files. But still cannot run the emulator.

Comment: Then just wipe the data and try

Comment: Now I tried and sitll not showing.

Comment: Go to AVD Manager and click on the down-arrow on the right and click Stop. This stops the emulator and you can re-run it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "Stop" Button on this down-arrow menu. That is really awkward. I think I should download the previous archives and try again. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: These file cannot be deleted while the emulator is running. Once stopped, they are deleted automatically. Still not showing in devices list. How to solve??